# IPC между C# приложением на Windows и Python приложением на Ubuntu внутри Virtual Box

Tags: c#, python, windows, virtualbox, virtual-hosts

Имеется C# приложение на Windows и Python приложение на Ubuntu внутри Virtual Box.

Как лучше всего реализовать межпроцессорное взаимодействие в этом случае?
Virtual Box находится на том же компьютере что и приложение C#.
В приоритете скорость.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам потребуется какой-то транспорт на сокетах(TCP/WS/HTTP), с прикладной обвязкой JSONRPC, JSON, или что-то бинарное. Если IP адреса гостевой и хостовой машины Вам, будут не доступны, по какой-либо причине, то дополнительно потребуется брокер. По изучайте RabbitMQ, MQTT. Если уточните требования, можно советовать что-то более конкретное.

Comment: IP адреса доступны.

Comment: Нужно передавать небольшие массивы байт (пара десятков килобайт) несколько раз в секунду

Comment: Тогда используйте UDP сокет, Для обмена данными. Можно еще для удобства использовать protobuf